# Having issues with activating constraints programmatically and getting errors

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, storyboard, constraints

Last night I posted a question on here where I used storyboards to set the constraints. I decided to test it with anchors and do constraints programmatically.

I am getting this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException',
>   reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors
>    and
>   
>   because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its
>   anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's
>   illegal.'

I know this has to do with views not being a subview of a certain other view however, I have checked it plenty of times and I don't know what to do.

here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
class editViewController: UIViewController {

let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
let moContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

var editnotes: addednotes?




let mainbackgroundview: UIView =
{
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .black
    view.alpha = 0.3

    return view
}()


let backgroundview1: UIView =
{
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .purple

    return view
}()


let edittasktextview1: UITextView = {
    let tv = UITextView()
    tv.backgroundColor = .black
    return tv
}()

    let cancelButton : UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Cancel", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleCancelButton), for: 
.touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

let doneButton1 : UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("Done", for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleDoneButton), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()



@objc func handleCancelButton() {

    edittasktextview1.endEditing(true)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}


@objc func handleDoneButton()
{
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    if edittasktextview1.text.isEmpty == true
    {
        moContext.delete(editnotes!)
    }
    else
    {
        editnotes?.sNote = edittasktextview1.text
    }
    var error: NSError?
    do {
        // Save The object

        try moContext.save()
        print("SAVED")
    } catch let error1 as NSError {
        error = error1
    }

    edittasktextview1.endEditing(true)

}



override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "NotificationID"), object: nil)

}
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //add something here
   // edittasktextview.becomeFirstResponder()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    navigationItem.title = "Edit Tasks"
    edittasktextview1.text = editnotes?.sNote
    backgroundview1.backgroundColor = editnotes?.sPriorityColor
    edittasktextview1.backgroundColor = .clear
    setupviews()
    //adding gesture to the background view to dismiss keyboard
    let dismisskeyboardgesture = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    dismisskeyboardgesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dismisskeyboard))


    let maskPath = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect: self.backgroundview1.bounds, byRoundingCorners:[.topLeft, .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize.init(width: 20.0, height: 0))
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.frame = self.backgroundview1.bounds
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
    self.backgroundview1.layer.mask = maskLayer
     view.backgroundColor = .clear


    //view.addGestureRecognizer(dismisskeyboardgesture)
    view.addSubview(mainbackgroundview)
   mainbackgroundview.addSubview(backgroundview1)
// view.addSubview(backgroundview1)
    backgroundview1.addSubview(edittasktextview1)
    backgroundview1.addSubview(cancelButton)
    backgroundview1.addSubview(doneButton1)
}

    @objc func dismisskeyboard()
   {
    edittasktextview1.endEditing(true)
   }


func setupviews()
{
   mainbackgroundview.anchorToTop(view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor)
    backgroundview1.anchor(view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 45, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)

    edittasktextview1.anchor(view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 40, leftConstant: 8, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 8, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 150)

    cancelButton.anchor(edittasktextview1.bottomAnchor, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 18, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 8, widthConstant: 40, heightConstant: 30)

   doneButton1.anchor(edittasktextview1.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, topConstant: 18, leftConstant: 8, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 40, heightConstant: 30)


}

}
```

Help will be appreciated, as I am stuck at this problem for nearly 18 hours :(

### UPDATE #1

Not getting the same error now, however, I am not able to set the backgroundview1 on the mainbackgroundview.

I am adding it as a subview:

```
mainbackgroundview.addSubview(backgroundview1)
```

In `setupviews()` I am placing the constraint like so:

```
 NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        backgroundview1.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainbackgroundview.leftAnchor, constant: 0),
        backgroundview1.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainbackgroundview.rightAnchor, constant: 0),
        backgroundview1.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainbackgroundview.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
        backgroundview1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainbackgroundview.topAnchor, constant: 45)

        ])
```

Still I am not getting the `backgroundview1` to be placed on the `mainbackgroundview`. The `mainbackgroundview` is showing up though on the simulator.

I am adding `mainbackgroundview` like so:

```
 NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        mainbackgroundview.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
        mainbackgroundview.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
        mainbackgroundview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
        mainbackgroundview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])
```

What am I doing wrong now?

Comment: you also missed to set yourView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false in all your views.Also set .isActive=true for constraints.

Comment: tried that. Still not working :(

Comment: "mainbackgroundview.addSubview(backgroundview1)". This adds "backgroundView1" on "mainbackgroundview" . So constraints for  "backgroundView1" should refer "mainbackgroundview"  , and not view.

Answer (score 0):

In setupViews() function you are adding constraints but not setting them as active. This is a sample anchor constraint that can be added successfully:

```
myView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor,
   constant: 8).isActive=true
```

Try adding .isActive at the end of each of your constraint.

Moreover you can add relevant anchor constraints for example: topAnchor, bottomAnchor, widthAnchor, heightAnchor, leadingAnchor etc. Try simplifying your constraints.

Comment: I have updated the post now. I am not getting the same error but can't seem to set constraint for a view that I placed on top of the mainbackgroundview.Please check it out!

Comment: Hey brother, I just checked your code. You are implementing it in a wrong order. Constraints could only be added once you have the view added into the main view. Call setupviews() at the end of viewdidload().